# Jmeter how i can get viewstat from between vertical bar

Tags: performance, automation, jmeter

in rispnse:

> __VIEWSTATE|/wEPZwUPOGQ1OWYxMzI0Y2UxZWQ5|

This [^|]+ is not working in my case.

I want this text

> /wEPZwUPOGQ1OWYxMzI0Y2UxZWQ5

Comment: Any feedback on answers ? If ok you should accept one and upvote so that answer is safely usable by others.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape '|' character:

> __VIEWSTATE\|(.+?)\|

Configuration of [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) would be:

[image]